# how can I put a logic in map array method. I have sent title as props and except props title I want to render other title

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: This is my code. When I use map method it maps every title in dummy data]

[image: Here, when I click bitcoin. Parent component sends bitcoin as title. I don't want to include bitcoin in the select tag.]
Here, when I click bitcoin. Parent component sends bitcoin as title. I don't want to include bitcoin in the select tag.

Comment: Please post actual code in a code snippet (not an image) and explain the question, what you tried, what your getting and what you want to get.

Comment: Use can use the filter method to filter out the current currency from the select https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the option directly from your map function, if you want to add logic inside just add `{}` and a `return` statement inside

```
{coins.map((item) => {
    // you can put your logic here
    // for example just first 2 letters
    const customTitle = item.title.slice(0, 2)
    return (
        <option>{customTitle}</option>
    )
})}
```

You can read more about `arrow functions` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)